# onclick method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding click events to dynamically created elements. This is my dynamic element creation method.

```
ajaxCall("/getItems","POST",data,function(result){
    var element = $('.item').first();
    $('#item-list-section').empty();

    for(var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++){
        var clone = element.clone();

        clone.attr("id", result.items[i].itemId);
        clone.find('.item-price').html("<h4>25</h4>");
        if(result.items[i].itemName.length > 20){
            clone.find('.item-name').css('overflow','hidden');
            clone.attr('title', result.items[i].itemName )
        }
        clone.find('.item-name').html("<h4>"+ result.items[i].itemName + "</h4>");

        clone.on('click',function(){
            showToolTip();
        });

        clone.draggable({
            revert : false,
            zIndex: 1,
            containment: "window",
            opacity: 0.5,
            cursor: "move",
            helper: function() { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show(); }
        });
        $('#item-list-section').append(clone);
    }
});
```

This is the click event function!

```
function showToolTip(){
    $newDiv = $('<div></div>');
    $newDiv.css("display", "none");
    $newDiv.addClass('tooltip');
    $newDiv.append('adfhadfhadfhadfh')
    $newDiv.appendTo("body");
    $newDiv.fadeIn().css(({ left:  e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
}
```

I used firebug debug points but it doesn't break from the click function!  Is is wrong the way I bind the click event!

Comment: Where is `$newDiv` assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the click event handler to the `'#item-list-section'` element outside of your `for` loop, it will fire on dynamically created elements within:

```
$('#item-list-section').on('click', 'element', function() { ... });
```

Here you can replace `element` with the cloned element type or any identifying classes as you usually would. If your cloned element was `<div class="myDiv">`, for example, you could use `'div'` or `'.myDiv'`, etc.

For example, if your markup ended up being something like:

```html
<div id="item-list-section">
    <div class="myClonedElement"></div>
    <div class="myClonedElement"></div>
    <div class="myClonedElement"></div>
</div>
```

You could bind the click event to the cloned element container using:

```
$('#item-list-section').on('click', '.myClonedElement', function() {
    showTooltip();
});
```

This way you don't need to create a new click event handler for every cloned element. You have one which caters for all.

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/wTCG6/).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code:

```
clone.on('click',function(){
```

with this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#' + result.items[i].itemId, function(){
```

Reference: [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: You probably need `'#' + result.items[i].itemId`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that original object has not a click callback already defined?

try:

```
clone.unbind("click");
```

before setting your callback